# Pyspark: How can I collect all worker logs in a specified single file in a yarn cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In my code I want to put some `logger.info('Doing something')`. Using standard library `logging` dosen't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use log4j for logging information in your application make sure to have log4j dependency provided in runtime with configured log4j.xml.

In order to aggregate logs, you need check following things

1. check whether **yarn.log-aggregation-enable** it set to **true** in **yarn-site.xml** and make sure necessary mount points are added in **yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir** and **yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir-suffix**.

   For example : **yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir=/mnt/app-logs,/mnt1/app-logs/**
   and **yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir-suffix=/logs/,/logs/**

   With the above settings,logs are aggregated in HDFS at "/mnt/app-logs/{username}**/logs/**". Under this folder,

   When the MapReduce/spark applications are running, then you can access the logs from the YARN's web UI. Once the application is completed, the logs are served through the [Job History Server](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html).
2. If your **yarn.log-aggregation-enable** is disable then you can check logs in this location of **yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs** in local node filesystem.

   For Example : **yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs=/mnt/hadoop/logs/,/mnt1/hadoop/logs/**
3. **yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds** -- This value only makes sense when you have a long-running job which will take more than 7 days. **(default value of yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds = 7 days )**, which means those logs will be available to aggregate till 7 days after that cleanup job will delete from nodes.

After checking the above properties, you can do few things

1. You can use yarn Resource manager UI and check the logs of current running job .If it is finished you can check logs via history server

(OR)

2. You can **ssh** to master node and do **yarn logs -applicationId appid** only after application is finished.

Note: make sure your job history server is up and running and configured with enough resources

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve all logs (driver and executor) of your application into one file this way
:

```
 yarn logs -applicationId <application id> /tmp/mylog.log
```

application id is the id of your application ... you can retrieve it from spark-history server if needed .

some exemple :  application_1597227165470_1073